# dynamic button not clicking in JS

Tags: javascript, html, servlets

I am parsing JSON data to add into a table and I need to implement pagination. To sort the data, the header elements must be buttons. The code runs fine except the sorting portion. The buttons are not generating any event. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

**Adding Buttons**

```
for ( var x in res) {

        for ( var y in res[x]) {

            tableData += "<td>";
            tableData += "<input type=\"button\" value=\"" + y
                    + "\" onclick=\"loadData(" + y + ")\" />";
            tableData += "</td>";
            alert(tableData);
        }
        break;
    }
```

**loadData function**

```
function loadData(modi) {

    var xhr = getXMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open("GET", "DbServlet?modifyQ=" + modi, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send(null);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {

        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {

            res = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

            paginate(res);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: may you provide a jsfiddle ?

Comment: Why would the alert show up when the button is clicked? You need to show your `loadData` function.

Comment: We need to see the content of 'loadData' function

Comment: Try using this `"<input type=\"button\" value=\"" + y + "\" onclick=\""+ loadData(y) + "\" />";` instead of this `"<input type=\"button\" value=\"" + y + "\" onclick=\"loadData(" + y + ")\" />";`

Comment: @Andy - yes.. let me put up the code for loadData..

Comment: @Troy - that does not help.. it turns into an infinite recursive call and Eclipse just crashes..

Comment: @iCoder_so7 Well then we will need to see your `loadData` function. It  might be because it doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked on it and found out the mistake. Its a simple issue with the single and double quotes. Since I used a string value as a parameter, I should have put up a combination of **`'" ... "'`** instead of `"..."`.

Working code is :

```
for ( var x in res) {

        for ( var j in res[x]) {
            tableData += "<td>";
            tableData += "<input type='button' value ='" + j
                    + "' onclick=\"loadData('" + "50r7" + j + "')\"/>";
            tableData += "</td>";
        }
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested your code on [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/L8jc9c5c/7/), you might have problem with the data. Your code does not add buttons to html so many missing points. I hope fiddle helps.

And better use console.log, or a div for printing "alert" is annoying.

```
var tableData = "";

window.loadData = function (a){
  $("#result").html(a);
}

var res = {"btn1":[11,12],"btn2":[21,22]};
for ( var x in res) {

        for ( var y in res[x]) {

            tableData += "<td>";
            tableData += "<input type=\"button\" value=\"" + y
                    + "\" onclick=\"loadData(" + y + ")\" />";
            tableData += "</td>";
            //alert(tableData);
        }
            $("#test").append($(tableData));
        break;
    }
```

Comment: The data I'm passing to my JS script looks like this : 

[{"ID":"6","Name":"Rotterdam","CountryCode":"NLD","District":"Zuid-Holland","Population":"593321"},{"ID":"7","Name":"Haag","CountryCode":"NLD","District":"Zuid-Holland","Population":"440900"}]

Comment: I used this in your fiddle.. It created the buttons but they do not click! Any idea why ?